# How to move character with touch on Android

Tags: android

I'm trying to make a game where you control a character via touch on Android devices.

The player will have two option of movement.

1- When you touch the touch screen and move your finger, the game object should move to your finger's location and follow your finger as you move it.

2-when you left your finger and touch in another place the character will go to the position where you touch your finger

please some help

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

show me some code, preferably your onTouch, are you using surfaceView?

we can help but thats a little vague.

heres what you need.  you need to capture you x and y coordinates, presumably in your case in a few different states, i.e.: when first touched, when touched while moving, and or touch up:

```
 @Override
  public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     tx = event.getX();
        ty = event.getY();

   int action = event.getAction();
   switch(action){
   case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
         tx = event.getX();
            ty = event.getY();
        obj.touchDown(tx,ty);
    break;
   case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
       tx = event.getX();
        ty = event.getY();
        obj.touchMove(tx,ty);


    break;
   case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
    obj.touchRelease(tx,ty);
    break;
   case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:

    break;
   case MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE:

    break;
   default:
   }
   return true; //processed
  }
```

then you need to implement these methods in your object class so it will respond. pathing from any point to a touched point is simple enough once you play around with it

in object class with above code in surfaceview

```
public void touchMove(float tx,float ty){
obj.x=tx;
obj.y=ty;

}
```

this will drag the item with your finger while you touch.